# Where is a Bundle variable saved in Activity?

Tags: android

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("x", x);
}
```

When I save a Bundle, Where is the Bundle variable exactly saved? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: fixed with an edit ... thanks for reporting, I didn't notice on first edit, just copied and pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29), you can read the source code to understand what has happened here.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBundle(WINDOW_HIERARCHY_TAG, mWindow.saveHierarchyState());
        Parcelable p = mFragments.saveAllState();
        if (p != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(FRAGMENTS_TAG, p);
        }
        getApplication().dispatchActivitySaveInstanceState(this, outState);
    }
```

In the source code, it's clear to see the state will be managed by `Application`. When the Activity is destroyed, the Application can help save relevant states. But, if you ever met this situation that Application was killed, you would find all states were lost. So, I think all states are kept in memory, not file like preference.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think you will find it and I don't expect to be referenced directly somewhere.

However its content will be available in [`onCreate(savedInstanceState)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) when the activity is recreated. Taken from its documentation: `savedInstanceState: If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut down then this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Note: Otherwise it is null`

Another place to look for its content is [`onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure I think you must set the int,string or whatever you want 
so as to save it into int
Let me show you an
**EXAMPLE**

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state){
super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
Int i = 1;
state.putInt("s",i);


}
```